# How can I optimize this snippet?

Tags: javascript

Being only able to glue pieces together to get some JS working, I came up with the following code.

```
if (document.getElementById("component_projector_askforproduct")){
  document.getElementById("component_projector_askforproduct").style.display = "none";
}
if (document.getElementById("askforproduct_58676")){
  document.getElementById("askforproduct_58676").className = "";
}
if (document.getElementById("longdescription_58676")){
  document.getElementById("longdescription_58676").className = "";
}

if (document.getElementById("opinions_58676")){
  document.getElementById("opinions_58676").className = "activTab";
}
if (document.getElementById("component_projector_opinions")){
  document.getElementById("component_projector_opinions").style.display = "block";
}
if (document.getElementById("component_projector_opinions_add")){
  document.getElementById("component_projector_opinions_add").style.display = "block";
}
```

It works, but I know it's a mess. How could I optimize and slim this code down?

Comment: Are you just checking if they are existing using the `if`?

Comment: Without knowing context, hard to answer. Leave it as it is, if it is working.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I am checking to see if the ID exists, if it does then it either sets an inline style or adds/removes a class. The reason I am checking if it exists first is because it would return NULL if the element is missing creating errors in the console.

Comment: @bskool Perfect. Leave it as is.

Comment: You might want to check out [codereview.se]. Please do read their help center to ensure it's on-topic, but they're generally the best place to go for, well, code reviews.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT I removed my last answer, and got an idea from Mirko Vukušićs answer.

if you create css classes for hiding and showing elements you could do it like this.

css

```
.hide { display: none!important; }
.show { display: block!important; }
```

javascript

```
var arr = [
  ["component_projector_askforproduct", "hide"],
  ["askforproduct_58676", ""],
  ["longdescription_58676", ""],
  ["opinions_58676", "activTab"],
  ["component_projector_opinions", "show"],
  ["component_projector_opinions_add", "show"]
]

for (i = 0; i < arr.length -1; i++) {
  var elm = document.getElementById(arr[i][0]);
  if(elm) {
    elm.className = arr[i][1];
  }
}
```

Comment: why the alert? That's not what the original code does in case an element is missing.

Comment: Better, hopefully it will work for all OP's cases... :)

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is:

1. use object to store all your changes like:

   ```
   var objChecks = {
     component_projector_askforproduct: "some_display_none_className",
     askforproduct_58676: "",
     longdescription_58676: ""
   }
   ```
2. then create function to process it (pass objChecks to it):

   ```
   function processChecks(checks) {
     Object.getOwnPropertyNames(objChecks).map(function(check){
       var el = document.getElementById(check);
       if (el) el.className=objChecks[check];
     })
   }
   ```
3. change your HTML a bit. I noticed sometimes you change `className` and sometimes `style.display`. I'd make a new class that hides an element (same as `display=none`) which makes everything much neater.

Answer (score 0):

use ternary conditions for code beautification.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

or use switch conditions.

suggestion : If i am in this scenario i would make specific function to perform this task and use ternary condition for code beautification.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid constant checking, and avoid errors, you can do this neat trick, to set default values:

```
function $(elem) {

return document.getElementById(elem) || document.createElement("div");
}
```

So, this way, if element doesn't exist, it will be created, but not appended to body!

Test:

```js
function $(elem) {

return document.getElementById(elem) || document.createElement("div");
}

$("component_projector_askforproduct").style.display = "none";
$("askforproduct_58676").className='';
$('longdescription_58676').className="";
$('opinions_58676').className="activeTab";
$("component_projector_opinions").style.display = "block";
//etc, etc....
```

```css
.activeTab {
  background:red;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="component_projector_askforproduct">
6666666666666
</div>
<div id="opinions_58676">
qqqqqqqqqqqqqq
</div>

<div id="component_projector_opinions7">
11111111111111
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After analyse question code I understand it is some kind of menu or tabs with possibility to activate,deactivate, show, hide elements. I created structure for this purposes with builded in methods. It can be used on many elements, it can be use on one element many times, it has also chain methods so it is possible to run many methods in one code line.

Check code of this structure and examples, if there is some questions or something is not clear then ask. I am not using ES6 or jQuery because this question is not about that.

```js
var ME = function(){ 
  //structure represent single menu element  
  var MenuElement = function(id){

    this.el = document.getElementById(id);
  
  };

  MenuElement.prototype.hide = function(){
  
    if (this.el)
    this.el.style.display = "none";
  
    return this;
  };

  MenuElement.prototype.show = function(){

    if (this.el)
    this.el.style.display = "block";
  
    return this;
  };

  MenuElement.prototype.active = function(){

    if (this.el)
    this.el.className = "activeTab";
  
    return this;
  
  };

  MenuElement.prototype.deActive = function(){

    if (this.el)
    this.el.className = "";
  
    return this;
  };
  
  //return only obj with create method to use it without new keyword
  return {
    create: function(id){      
      return new MenuElement(id);
    }
  };
  
}();

//USE EXAMPLE - the same like in question snippet
ME.create("component_projector_askforproduct").hide();
ME.create("askforproduct_58676").deActive();
ME.create("longdescription_58676").deActive();
ME.create("opinions_58676").active();
ME.create("component_projector_opinions").show();
ME.create("component_projector_opinions_add").show();

//USE EXAMPLE MANY TIMES ON ONE ELEMENT - ONLY EXAMPLE PURPOSES
var element = ME.create("component_projector_askforproduct");
var toggle = true;
setInterval(function(){
   
   if (toggle)
   element.show().active(); //chaining example
   else
     element.deActive().hide();
  
   toggle = !toggle;
  
},1000);
```

```css
div.activeTab {
     font-weight: bold;
     color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div id="component_projector_askforproduct">
component_projector_askforproduct
</div>
<div id="askforproduct_58676">
askforproduct_58676
</div>
<div id="longdescription_58676">
longdescription_58676
</div>
<div id="opinions_58676">
opinions_58676
</div>
<div id="component_projector_opinions">
component_projector_opinions
</div>
<div id="component_projector_opinions_add">
component_projector_opinions_add
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not call getElementById twice for the same ID. Store return value in a variable, and check that before trying to manipulate it.